# Positive distance between sets of a compact convex family

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

So I'm struggling with this exercise from Lay's Convex Sets:

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of compact convex sets in $\mathbb R^n$ containing at least $n+1$ members. Suppose that for each subfamily of $n+1$ members there exists a point $x$ such that all sets in the subfamily are at a distance less or equal than $d \ge 0$ from $x$. Then there exists $y$ such that all sets in $\mathcal F$ are at a distance $ \le d$ from $y$.

I feel like I should use Helly's theorem, but it is not clear to me how to.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Special case : Consider points in ${\bf R}^2$ If $C$ is smallest circle of radius
$r$ which bounds all points. Note that two or more points is in $C$.
If two points only is in $C$, then their distance attains $2r$.

If three or more points is in $C$, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is typical question amendable by [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem#Statement).

Say $\mathcal F = (F_j)_{j \in J}$, and let $d \ge 0$ be as in the announcement. It's clear that for each $j \in J$, the set $X_j := \{x \in \mathbb R^n| \mathrm{dist}(F_j, x) \le d\}$ is convex and compact. Now for any $n + 1$ indices $j_1, \ldots, j_{n+1} \in J$, the hypothesis ensures that there is a point $x$ which is at distance $\le d$ from any $F_{j_k}$, i.e $x \in \cap_{1 \le k \le n + 1}X_{j_k}$. But then Helly's theorem implies $\cap_{j \in J}X_j \ne \emptyset$, i.e there exists a point which is at a distance $\le d$ from any $F \in \mathcal F$.